Slow response after adding lighthouse php graphql package
I use lighthouse-php package to implement graphql.
However the response time increases too much.
I simply run project on docker env with php and mongodb.
I make a simple query type from a single collection. it took 2000ms+ to respond result..
I tried to add pagination but still it took same time.
I use debugger to see performance. DB queries are optimized, they took only 7ms to execute query results. but I don't understand why overall request took 2000ms+.
I check docker volumes. they are proper sets.. ignored vendor directory. As I implement first time so I don't have idea that this time is standard for graphql to parse and execute queries or something went wrong with my scenario.
here a simple query time and resolver:
QUERY
type Query {
    resultPages(filters: FilterInput,  page: Int, limit: Int): ResultPagesPagination @field(resolver: "App\\GraphQL\\Resolvers\\ResultPagesResolver@ResultPages") 
}

Resolver
public function ResultPage($root, array $args, GraphQLContext $context, ResolveInfo $resolveInfo)
    {
        $query = ResultPage::query();

        if (isset($args['filters']) && isset($args['filters']['rules'])) {
            $this->applyFilters($query, $args['filters']['rules'], $args['filters']['combinator'] ?? 'and');
        }

 

        // Pagination
        $page = $args['page'] ?? 1;
        $pageSize = $args['limit'] ?? 10;
        $totalResults = $query->count();

        $data = $query->skip(($page - 1) * $pageSize)
            ->take($pageSize)
            ->get();

        return [
            'data' => $data,
            'currentPage' => $page,
            'totalPages' => ceil($totalResults / $pageSize),
            'totalCount' => $totalResults
        ];

}


I tried to add pagination. but still took same time to complete request... I also notice other rest apis in project almost took their native time before adding graphql but only graphql took too much time. either this is graphql normal behaviour or there problems in my implementation
clockwork profiling:
enter image description here

Is this docker on windows/linux/mac? Or is it windows with wsl then docker inside?

docker on window with wsl 2 engine

docker logs anything?

2024-05-29 16:39:02   2024-05-29 11:39:02 ................................................... ~ 0s
2024-05-29 16:39:09   2024-05-29 11:39:08 ................................................... ~ 0s
2024-05-29 16:39:16   2024-05-29 11:39:13 ................................................... ~ 3s
it just only shows time to complete but that details would not be enough to figure out
